# Algorithm for solving systems which are nearly symmetric/adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I am familiar with Cholesky decomposition and LU factorization for solving systems of linear equations.

I have a problem where I have large sparse matrices (say, 1000x1000 or larger) where only one or two rows/columns (last couple rows/columns) break symmetry.  I understand that Cholesky is nearly twice as efficient as LU, but I can't use Cholesky due to these outlier rows/columns.

Is there another method or algorithm that can handle this particular case - i.e., take advantage of the fact that nearly the entire matrix is self-adjoint/symmetric (real values only here)?

Comment: Performing an LU decomposition $O(2/3 n^{3})$ on a system with $O(n)$ entries is over expensive. As a consequence, Stationary method such as Jacobi iteration, Gauss-Seidel, and SOR method were developed but these methods were popular in 1950s and are considered old-fashion. Now you could resort to the highly advanced Krylov methods to solve sparse systems. On MATLAB you can use the command ```bicgstab()``` to solve this sparse system https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bicgstab.html

Comment: Various strategies come to mind, including the one suggested in @StevenRoberts 's answer and [Schur complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Application_to_solving_linear_equations), but I think that the real challenge is coming up with something that is provably stable (or, at least, as unstable as solving the original system with LU factorization): if at any point you invert another matrix instead of $A$, that matrix may be ill-conditioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's express the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with which we want to solve linear systems as
$$
A = S + U V
$$
where $S$ is a symmetric matrix, $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$.  That is, $U V$ is a low rank update to account for the lack of symmetry.  From your question, it appears $r$ is just 1 or 2.

The [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) tells us that
$$
A^{-1} x = (I_{n \times n} - \underbrace{S^{-1} U (I_{r \times r} + V S^{-1} U)^{-1}}_{W} V) S^{-1} x = (I_{n \times n} - W V) S^{-1} x.
$$
Now, inverses appear for the symmetric matrix $S$.  During the preprocessing step, you can compute the Cholesky factorization of $S$ and precompute $W = S^{-1} U (I_{r \times r} + V S^{-1} U)^{-1}$.  Note that $W$ only requires $\mathcal{O}(r n^2)$ flops to compute, and that should be neglidgible.

After preprocessing, a linear system can be solved with $(I_{n \times n} - W V) S^{-1} x$.  Working right to left, we can use forward/back substitution to compute $S^{-1} x$.  Then, we need to perform a matrix-vector multiplication with $\left( I_{n \times n} - W V \right)$.  At a cost of $\mathcal{O}(r n)$, that is neglidgible.